# JMS Serialize @VirtualProperty doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I'm trying to add a method to serialize, but JMS Serialize does not show the field.

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\VirtualProperty;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName;

class Ads
{   
    /**
     * @VirtualProperty
     * @Type("string")
     * @SerializedName("Foo")
     * @Groups({"manage"})
     */
    public function foo(){
        $foo = 'foo';
        return $foo;
    }
    ...
}
```

And then:

```
use JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext;
use JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder;

...

$context = new SerializationContext();
$context->setGroups(array('manage'));

$serializer = JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
$jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($ad, 'json', $context);
```

I have not seen any examples of how to use VirtualProperty.

Is the syntax correct? What is wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed the problem. There was created before the object "$ ad". My fault. Virtual property functioning properly.

Comment: What was the problem? How did you fix it? Try the same with a yaml config,  not work either... Thanks.

Comment: Ok found why. Yaml configuration is quite different. You have to separate virtual properties. See here: http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/yml_reference

Comment: This is supposed to explain where was the problem but I don't understand that sentence ... :(

Comment: If somebody (like me) doesn't understand the answer, this will maybe help you. In my case, the problem was that I have not add `use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\VirtualProperty;` and `use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName;` at the top of my file